# WPF buttons won't fire in windowState = "maximized"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a WPF application that I want to continually run on a device.  As a result, I want it to take up the maximum screen size of whatever device it's running on.  I can get the application to take up the whole screen, but when I do, none of my buttons will fire.  I have to resize the window and then the buttons will fire.  Anyone know why this happens?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ExchangeCalendar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CalendarDataSource"/>


</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="settings_btn"/>
    <Button Content="Add Meeting" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="add_meeting_btn"/>
    <DataGrid Name ="CalendarData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="251" Margin="196,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalendarDataSource}}"/>
    <Label Content="Utilimap Conference Room" Margin="49,10,67.4,261.4" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="28"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="302" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="508" Margin="10,0,0,10.4">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="22*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="129*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="Connection_lbl" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="277,129,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    #region Properties_and_variables
    /*Properties*/
    private String Domain { get; set; }
    private String SharedCal { get; set; }
    private String username { get; set; }
    private String Password { get; set; }
    private ExchangeVersion version { get; set; }
    public List<MeetingData> Appointments { get; set; }

    /*Variables*/
    private ExchangeService service;
    private bool validCredentials = true;
    private FolderId shareFolderId;
    private CalendarView calendar;
    #endregion

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Appointments = new List<MeetingData>();

    }

    #region Buttons

    /*Settings Button clicked*/
    private void settings_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsDialog op = new SettingsDialog();

        if ((bool)op.ShowDialog(this.username, this.Password, this.SharedCal, this.Domain, this.version)){
            set_setting_properties(op);
            connect_to_exchange();
        }
    }

    //Add Meeting Button Clicked
    private void add_meeting_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new dialog for adding a meeting
        AddMeeting meetingToAdd = new AddMeeting();
        bool[] results = room_availability();
        MeetingData newMeeting = new MeetingData("", "", "", "WinExchangeCalendar", 60);

        //Get user data
        if (meetingToAdd.ShowDialog(newMeeting, results))
            add_new_meeting_to_cal(newMeeting);

    }
```

Comment: Try setting `VerticalAlignment="Top"` against `Label` as it covers your `Buttons` but as a long term solution use different layout panel that goes with the flow like `DockPanel` or define rows/columns in your `Grid`, instead of position elements via `Margin` with fixed `Width`/`Height`, especially that you want to take all available space.

Comment: Whatever problem you are having with your `Button`s is not related to having a full screen application. To confirm this, create a new project, make it full screen, add a `Button` and click it. You will see that the handler get called as expected. Therefore, it is most likely that it is some of *your* code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Sheridan I'm sure that my code is causing the problem, but I'm confused because if I just move the window, it will scale down to the 350x525 size and the buttons will then fire.  That's why I believe it's linked.

Comment: Sometimes when we have problems like this, the only thing that we can do to find the problem is to try to recreate it in a simple project. Therefore, if you start a new project and copy the immediate code into it bit by bit, one of two things normally happens: Either you will find that the new project does *not* have the problem, in which case you should be able to spot the difference, or it *will* have the problem, in which case you can post it here to be tested. The essential part is to remove all unrelated code, like the `ExchangeService` related classes.